# Как отключить всплывающие подсказки когда печатаю в eclipse mars 4.5.0

Tags: eclipse

Для PHP и JS я хочу отключить эти подсказки, все настройки облазил, нашел только подсказки при наведении, отключил их, а как отключить те, которые появляются когда печатаешь? Я печатаю, к примеру:
`trim` и редактор выдает подсказку об этой функции и о многих других которые есть в PHP и JS, если начать печатать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу отключить их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходите в Preferences. В строке поиска вбиваете "Assist". В всех появившихся "Content Assist" отключаете "Enable auto activation". После этого подсказка будет появляться только по нажатии ctrl+Space.